# How can I find my sensor id if it's not showing up on lsusb?

Tags: 22.04, asus, fingerprint-reader

I dualbooted my windows 11 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. But I've been unable to use my laptop's built-in fingerprint sensor.

The allow fingerprint authentication setting is just not present.

I searched a bit and found that not allow sensors are supported and got the list of supported sensors, which is [here](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html).

I ran `lsusb` to see the name of my fingerprint sensor and check if it's available or not, but the name wasn't present in the list.

Now some details for you guys:

1. Does the sensor even work? : Yes I use it easily in my windows partition.
2. Name of my laptop : Asus Vivobook 15 X1502ZA
3. Name of my sensor found in the windows device manager: Elan WBF fingerprint sensor
4. I then checked the properties in the device manager and got these hardware ids :

```
ACPI\VEN_ELAN&DEV_7001
ACPI\ELAN7001
*ELAN7001
```

5. This is what `lsusb` returns: Yes, just five lines.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3277:0029 Shine-optics USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

6. Someone mentioned somewhere that the sensor might be turned off in the BIOS: Not the case for me as I use it in my windows partition.

I can't even check if my sensor is supported as the `xxxx:xxxx` ID is just not available to me. I see the name Elan in the list of supported sensors but there are lots of Elan sensors. To see if mine is supported, I want that ID. Can they be found by the hardware ids I found in the windows device manager.

Tell me if anything else is needed.

Thank You

Comment: Check the other busses, might not be on the USB bus.  The sd bus may be used, look in /sys/bus/sdio

Comment: @ubfan1, Both the folders, Devices and Drivers, inside the sdio are empty.

Comment: OK not on the sdio bus.  lspci for the pci bus, and if nothing obvious, maybe wade through the  dmidecode output to see the device details.

Comment: Watch your system start up and detect its hardware with the terminal command `sudo journalctl -b 0`.